# Android app to convert from multiple currencies to one

Tags: android, currency-converter

I am looking for an Android application which can convert from multiple currencies to one. Every currency converter/calculator I've checked on Play Store is doing exactly opposite what I want. Do you have a tip for such application?

What I basically want is to enter number in input field and it will take this as a base value in multiple currencies (eg. USD,GBP,JPY) and converts it to 1 home currency (eg. EUR).